# Weird vertical space in CSS

Tags: css

**CSS**

```
#leftFlyBanner {
  position:fixed; 
  _position:absolute;  
  width: 118px; 
  top:180px; 
  left:10px; 
  float:left;
}

#leftFlyBanner ul { 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  list-style: none; 
  width:118px; 
  float:left;
}

#leftFlyBanner ul li {
  display: inline; 
  margin:0 ; 
  padding:0; 
  float:left;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="leftFlyBanner">
  <ul>
     <li><TITLE IMAGE></li>
       <li id="s2">
            <IMAGE1 />
            <IMAGE2 />
            <IMAGE3 />
       </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When I open in IE & Chrome there is space between TITLE IMAGE and images below.
How can I remove that vertical space?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Uh. There is no 'TITLE IMAGE' or 'bellow images' in your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
#leftFlyBanner img {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#leftFlyBanner ul li { line-height:0 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/rY3DJ/